# Sequence Aggregation with Time Series Data in Graph Database

Tags: time-series, combinations, sequence, graph-databases, combinatorics

All,

I am new to the graph database area and want to know if this type of example if applicable to a graph database.

Say I am looking at a baseball game. When each player goes to bat, there are 3 possible outcomes: hit, strikeout, or walk.

For each batter and throughout the baseball season, what I want to figure out is the counts of the sequences.

For example, for batters that went to the plate n times, how many people had a particular sequence (e.g, hit/walk/strikeout or hit/hit/hit/hit), and if so, how many of the same batters repeated the same sequence indexed by time. To further explain, time would allow me know if a particular sequence (e.g. hit/walk/strikeout or hit/hit/hit/hit) occurred during the beginning of the season, in the mid, or later half.

For a key-value type database, the raw data would look as follows:

```
Batter      Time        Game    Event       Bat
-------     -----       ----    ---------   ---
Charles     April       1       Hit         1
Charles     April       1       strikeout   2
Charles     April       1       Walk        3
Doug        April       1       Walk        1
Doug        April       1       Hit         2
Doug        April       1       strikeout   3
Charles     April       2       strikeout   1
Charles     April       2       strikeout   2
Doug        May         5       Hit         1
Doug        May         5       Hit         2
Doug        May         5       Hit         3
Doug        May         5       Hit         4
```

Hence, my output would appear as follows:

```
Sequence                    Freq        Unique Batters  Time
-----------------------     ----        --------------  ------
hit                         5000        600             April
walk/strikeout              3000        350             April
strikeout/strikeout/hit     2000        175             April
hit/hit/hit/hit/hit         1000        80              April
hit                         6000        800             May
walk/strikeout              3500        425             May
strikeout/strikeout/hit     2750        225             May
hit/hit/hit/hit/hit         1250        120             May
.                           .           .               .
.                           .           .               .
.                           .           .               .
.                           .           .               .
```

If this is feasible for a graph database, would it also scale? What if instead of 3 possible outcomes for a batter, there were 10,000 potential outcomes with 10,000,000 batters?

More so, the 10,000 unique outcomes would be sequenced in a combinatoric setting (e.g. 10,000 CHOOSE 2, 10,000 CHOOSE 3, etc.).

My question then is, if a graphing database is appropriate, how would you propose setting up a solution?

Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Graph databases have come a long way since this question was asked but the answer to the question is, absolutely yes, a graph database can be used to find batter performance patterns.

*Disclaimer: I am the Director of Field Operations for Objectivity, Inc.*

This isn't a product plug. This problem can be solved in many of the products on the market. You specifically mention scaling the problem up and that may well be the limiting factor for some products.

To solve this problem I am using the Objectivity/DB database which is a massively scalable, object/graph database with a full-featured graph navigational query language called DO for Declarative Objectivity.

Here is the schema that I used to approach the problem:

```
CREATE CLASS Season  {
    year                : Integer,      
    games               : List { Element: Reference { referenced: Game }, CollectionTypeName: TreeListOfReferences }        
}

CREATE CLASS Game {
    date                : DateTime,
    homeTeam            : Reference { referenced: Team, inverse: homeGames },
    awayTeam            : Reference { referenced: Team, inverse: awayGames },
    from                : Reference { referenced: Season, inverse: games },
    innings             : Reference { referenced: Inning, inverse: game }
}

CREATE CLASS Inning {
    number              : Integer,
    game                : Reference { referenced: Game, inverse: innings },
    batters             : Reference { referenced: AtBat, inverse: inning }
}

CREATE CLASS AtBat {
    result              : String,
    inning              : Reference { referenced: Inning, inverse: batters },
    batter              : Reference { referenced: Player, inverse: atBats },
    nextAtBat           : Reference { referenced: AtBat, inverse: prevAtBat },
    prevAtBat           : Reference { referenced: AtBat, inverse: nextAtBat },
    nextBatter          : Reference { referenced: AtBat, inverse: prevBatter },
    prevBatter          : Reference { referenced: AtBat, inverse: nextBatter }
}

CREATE CLASS Player {
    name                : String,
    teams               : List { Element: Reference { EdgeClass: PlayedFor, EdgeAttribute: team }, CollectionTypeName: TreeListOfReferences },
    atBats              : List { Element: Reference { referenced: AtBat, inverse: batter }, CollectionTypeName: TreeListOfReferences }
}

CREATE CLASS PlayedFor {
    player              : Reference { referenced: Player, inverse: teams },
    team                : Reference { referenced: Team, inverse: players },
    start               : DateTime,
    end                 : DateTime
}

CREATE CLASS Team {
    name                : String,
    homeGames           : Reference { referenced: Game, inverse: homeTeam },
    awayGames           : Reference { referenced: Game, inverse: awayTeam },        
    players             : List { Element: Reference { EdgeClass: PlayedFor, EdgeAttribute: team }, CollectionTypeName: TreeListOfReferences }
}
```

Here is a summary of the schema. Every Player is connected to every one of their own AtBat objects. The AtBat objects for each player exists as a doubly-linked list. Every AtBat object points back to the Player that owns it.

A sample dataset might look like this:
[image]

The idea is to find a user-defined sequence of AtBat objects and then find the Player that owned that sequence. In the query below, we are looking for a "Strike Out", a "Hit", and a "Strike Out" pattern. When we find that pattern, we need to know the Player associated with that pattern. Because all AtBat objects are linked back to the owning Player, all we have to do in our query is express our desired sequence of AtBat objects and then navigate from the last AtBat object to the Player object it is connected to. The query is as follows:

```
match path = (a1:AtBat {result == "Strike Out"})
           -[:nextAtBat]->(a2:AtBat {result == "Hit"})
           -[:nextAtBat]->(a3:AtBat {result == "Strike Out"})
           -->(p:Player) 
           group by p.name
           return a1.result, a2.result, a3.result, p.name;
```

A sample of results are shown below:

```
{
  _Projection
  {
    a1.result:'Strike Out',
    a2.result:'Hit',
    a3.result:'Strike Out',
    p.name:'Player0_TeamA'
  },
  _Projection
  {
    a1.result:'Strike Out',
    a2.result:'Hit',
    a3.result:'Strike Out',
    p.name:'Player0_TeamB'
  },
  _Projection
  {
    a1.result:'Strike Out',
    a2.result:'Hit',
    a3.result:'Strike Out',
    p.name:'Player10_TeamA'
  },
```

This image depicts finding the pattern and then navigating from the last AtBat up to the associated Player:

[image]