# Sequences in Graph Database

Tags: database, graph, sequence, graph-databases

All,

I am new to the graph database area and want to know if this type of example if applicable to a graph database.

Say I am looking at a baseball game. When each player goes to bat, there are 3 possible outcomes: hit, strikeout, or walk.

For each batter and throughout the baseball season, what I want to figure out is the counts of the sequences.

For example, for batters that went to the plate n times, how many people had a particular sequence (e.g, hit/walk/strikeout or hit/hit/hit/hit), and if so, how many of the same batters repeated the same sequence indexed by time. To further explain, time would allow me know if a particular sequence (e.g. hit/walk/strikeout or hit/hit/hit/hit) occurred during the beginning of the season, in the mid, or later half.

For a key-value type database, the raw data would look as follows:

```
  Batter      Time        Game    Event       Bat
  -------     -----       ----    ---------   ---
  Charles     April       1       Hit         1
  Charles     April       1       strikeout   2
  Charles     April       1       Walk        3
  Doug        April       1       Walk        1
  Doug        April       1       Hit         2
  Doug        April       1       strikeout   3
  Charles     April       2       strikeout   1
  Charles     April       2       strikeout   2
  Doug        May         5       Hit         1
  Doug        May         5       Hit         2
  Doug        May         5       Hit         3
  Doug        May         5       Hit         4
```

Hence, my output would appear as follows:

```
 Sequence                    Freq        Unique Batters  Time
 -----------------------     ----        --------------  ------
 hit                         5000        600             April
 walk/strikeout              3000        350             April
 strikeout/strikeout/hit     2000        175             April
 hit/hit/hit/hit/hit         1000        80              April
 hit                         6000        800             May
 walk/strikeout              3500        425             May
 strikeout/strikeout/hit     2750        225             May
 hit/hit/hit/hit/hit         1250        120             May
 .                           .           .               .
 .                           .           .               .
 .                           .           .               .
 .                           .           .               .
```

If this is feasible for a graph database, would it also scale? What if instead of 3 possible outcomes for a batter, there were 10,000 potential outcomes with 10,000,000 batters?

More so, the 10,000 unique outcomes would be sequenced in a combinatoric setting (e.g. 10,000 CHOOSE 2, 10,000 CHOOSE 3, etc.).

My question then is, if a graphing database is appropriate, how would you propose setting up a solution?

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Graph databases are not graphing databases. They aren't used to graph data per se. They store data as a graph, nodes and edges between the nodes. They allow you to query this data as a graph. You typically use them if you have data that's highly connected and want to get some insight into this data. From your description, it doesn't look like that's what you want to do , right ?

Comment: So, what I'd like to know is the edges between the nodes in the "graph" database, can you aggregate them and put a time index on top of that? My goal is to see if there is a more efficient solution to aggregating sequences than utilizing python code to pull from a key-value pair database. What I'd like to know is if my example would work in a graph database. Specifically, can I get the sequences of bats by hitters and their counts across time?... Thanks in advance.

Comment: I posted an answer to the other instance of this same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244199/sequence-aggregation-with-time-series-data-in-graph-database/66549996#66549996